# How can I get multiple parameters from a URL in PHP?

Tags: php, url, get

I have 2 variables to send records.php, '$id' and '$row[0]". After it, I want to use them in newrecords.php with $_Get method.

Here 's index.php

```
 echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="newrecords.php?mid=&id=' . $id . $row[0] . '"$ >'.  $row[3] . "&nbsp;" . $row[4] .'</a></td>';
```

There's something going wrong.I see this url "newrecords.php?mid=&id=44"
i want to see like this "mid=4&id=4" and after this

newrecords.php

```
if (isset($_GET['mid']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['mid'];
}

if (isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $nid = $_GET['id'];
    }
```

Is it right way to get them?

Comment: That is the right way to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You URL is malformed. You have to separate each key/value with a `&`. And better use `&amp;` if it's in HTML.

```
echo('<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="newrecords.php?id='.
      $id.'&amp;mid='.$row[0].'"$ >'.$row[3]."&nbsp;".$row[4].'</a></td>');
```

So the structure is `?key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3`

That way you can get them with `$_GET['key1']` and `$_GET['key2']` and `$_GET['key3']`.

The way you get them, you are using isset, that's tricky because they might be set but have no value. You can also use `empty()` for that. It actually checks whether a value is not 0 or empty. So if you don't use 0 as a record id you can better use that. And I also if they are id's I would cast them (making sure they are integers)

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
if (!empty($id)){ ... }
```

Comment: Do not need to isset them?

Comment: Well, that depends, of course is more neat to do that. I would rather advice you to use `if (!empty($_GET['key1'])){..}`. That way if a value is empty, it gets false. `isset` also returns `true` with empty values.

If your values are always numbers, you can secure the thing a bit to force casting them to integers. By using `$key1 = (int)$_GET['key1']; if (!empty($key1)){..}`

Answer (score 5):

your url is not correct try this

```
echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="newrecords.php?mid='.$id.'&id='.$row[0].'" >'.  $row[3] . '&nbsp;' . $row[4] .'</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing? i think it is wrong. It will show url like "newrecords.php?mid=&id=44"  this instead of your code you should try like this.

```
echo '<td align="center">'.$row[0].'-)&nbsp;<a href="newrecords.php?mid='.$id.'&id='.$row[0].'" >'.  $row[3] . '&nbsp;' . $row[4] .'</a></td>';
```