# How to filter content based on multiple URL query values on PHP

Tags: php, url, filter

I have a page where URL query has multiple values. http://website/action?id=a,b,c

I was able to filter page content if the value is singlular. (http://website/action?id=a)

```
if($_GET['id'] == 'a'){
    echo "<p>This is 'a'</p>";  
}
```

How can I filter if id has multiple values? (http://website/action?id=a,b,c,x,z)

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is similar to what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177673/how-can-i-get-multiple-parameters-from-a-url-in-php

Comment: Thanks, but this is something dirrefent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the a,b,c,x,z string into an array using explode().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

You'll then be able to access each element separately.

```
$arr = explode(",", $_GET['id']);

// $arr[0] now equals a
// $arr[1] now equals b
// $arr[2] now equals c
// $arr[3] now equals x
// $arr[4] now equals z
```

Comment: What I what to do is to get values based on the URL query value, the order can be ordered randomly: http://website/action?id=a,b,c or http://website/action?id=c,a,b etc.  How can I use it in if condition?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following solution:

```
$arr = explode(", ", $_GET['id']);

if(in_array("a", $arr)){
    echo "<pre>This array has 'a'</pre>";   
}

if(in_array("b", $arr)){
    echo "<pre>This array has 'b'</pre>";   
}
```